# Difference of webdriver.keyboard.sendkeys() and webelement.sendkeys()

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver, sendkeys

For automation testing with Selenium, I found using the `webdriver.keyboard.senkeys(elementCoordinates)` seems like a more reliable way to locate and sendkeys to the element compared to `webElement.sendKeys()`. Basically, they should all be designed for the same function, but why one could work but sometimes the other doesn't work?

Comment: Where do you get `WebDriver.keyboard`? I do not see it in the API: https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html

Comment: it's under OpenQA.Selenium.Reomote